# How to Bold Headers in Python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I have tried `.bold = True` but it doesn't work, I am able to align it in the centre but unable to bold the font

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGomP.png)

[Word Document Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNYqF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "p.text = 'ABC'", you can write "p.add_run("ABC").bold=True".
With the help of this, you can also use underlines or italics.